# Как реализовать Stage, scenes в Golang для Телеграм бота(telegram bot api)

Tags: telegram-bot, golang, telegram

Есть бот который ведет себя по разному в зависимости нажатых кнопок. То есть если он нажимал кнопку "оставить отзывы" и написал тескт после чего этот текст надо будет переслать другим пользователям. А если он нажал "Поиск" тогда обрабатывать этот текст как искомое.

Есть ли вариант, кроме записи в базу данных нынешную позицию пользователя?

Comment: зависит от вашей реализации. расскажите по-подробнее о вашей схеме. как храните состояние, как идет дальше от одного состояния к другой

Comment: я вообще то думал что с api само приходит. Есть вариант хранить в БД , в таблице users и туда добавить колонку с состояниями. Но это решение не очень мне нравиться потому что потом надо будет каждый раз подключиться к бд и оттуда прочитать.  Есть ещё вариант сессиями но я с ними не имел дело, незнаю как это реализовывать на telegramapi

Comment: можно хранить в памяти статус по пользователю, например в map